# Правила перекомпиляции

Tags: java

Каковы конкретные правила инкрементной компиляции зависимых модулей? Я понимаю кухню java и могу некоторые правила вывести логически, но вдруг я случайно ошибусь?

PS: Еще я понимаю что все юзают maven/ant и не парятся :)

UPD: Неужели никто не знает?

Comment: Непонятно, о каких правилах речь. `javac` компилирует то, что его просят.

Comment: Если у меня есть Main.class и DoIt.class - если я изменю и перекомпилирую DoIt.class, а Main.class не перекомпилирую  это может вызвать проблемы. Я хочу найти конкретные правила, что можно изменять без перекомпиляции зависимого кода, а чего нельзя.

Comment: Или Вы хотите сказать, что в javac уже встроены все проверки инкрементной компиляции?

Comment: Компилируй все нужные *.java файлы, чтобы отсечь такие ошибки на этапе компиляции.

Comment: Это может понизить скорость компиляции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При инкрементальной компиляции необходимо перекомпилировать изменённые модули и их деревья зависимостей.

Для определения этих зависимостей надо анализировать сорцы.
Поэтому удобнее использовать одну из систем сборки (ant,maven,gradle) или полагаться на встроенную в IDE.

Comment: А конкретных правил нигде нет? Их все знают только разработчики maven и тп?:)

Comment: Например, разработчик библиотек java обязан знать эти правила, для совместимости при обновлениях.

Comment: @uskabuska, Нет никаких правил, есть здравый смысл: изменили public/protected интерфейс - пересобирайте, всех, кто его использует.

Comment: А изменение иерархии наследования?

Comment: Туда же. При нестыковке версий классов у вас могут случится 2 плохие вещи: не найден класс, к которому производится обращение (`NoClassDefFoundError`), и не найден вызываемый метод класса (`NoSuchMethodError`). Вот этим двум проблемам и нужно противодействовать.

Comment: *разработчик библиотек java обязан знать эти правила*. Не очень. Нет никакой проблемы при обновлении версии библиотеки пересобрать проект (более того, нет причин так не делать).